# entire function with constant modulus on circle -Schwarz reflection principle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function whose modulus is constant on some circle. Show that $f(z)=f(z_0) + c(z-z_0)^n$ for some $n \geqslant 0$ and some constant $c$, where $z_0$ is the center of the circle.

I only know a sketch of the proof, using Schwarz reflection Principle. I would seriously appreciate giving details to it.

Comment: It seems kind of related, but I don`t really think it`s exactly the sam.